# Template and deque

Tags: c++

I'm trying to work with deque and template and I wanted to add others files (func.cpp and func.h) so I can declare all my function in these files and then include func.h in main.cpp but I got an some errors:
1. argument list for variable template "display" is missing in main.cpp
2.'deque': undeclared identifier in func.cpp
3.'d': undeclared identifier in func.cpp

here's the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>
#include "funcr.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    deque <int> d1{ 1,5,3,9 };
    d1.push_front(2);
    display(d1);
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the func.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<typename T>
void display(deque<T> d)
{
    for (auto e : d)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

and there is the func.h:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
void display(deque<T>d);
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: Apart from template implementation in the header, the error in `func.cpp` is due the reason that `deque` in function argument should be `std::deque`. In addition, the header is included in the source file if you're trying to achieve the separate interface and implementation. And, in `main.cpp` the header file included is `funcr.h` but the actual file name is `func.h`.

Comment: thanks, but if I declare it in header file, then I must declare a template in both header file and main.cpp, then it would be redundancy, is this right?

Comment: The template function would be defined in the header file (`func.h`) and it'll be included in `main.cpp`. You won't be declaring but including.

Answer (score 0):

You must define `display` in `func.h`, because templated functions must be implemented in header files unless they are explicitly instantiated.

Also, you did not write `using namespace std;` in `func.h` ([not that you should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) write it anywhere, especially headers). As a result, you need to write `std::deque` instead of merely `deque`.

So `func.h` should look like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

template<typename T>
void display(const std::deque<T>& d)
{
    for (auto e : d)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: why I can't use an other file .cpp to implement the definition of display and in the header file(func.h) just the declaration?

Comment: Your question was closed. See the question that it's a duplicate of, as that will explain it.